# Selecting datatable based on the name of provider and the user name currently logged in

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

users table
[image: I added the data of my 'users' table]

mandates table
[image: And this is the 'mandates' table that I want to select based on the provider's name.]

I would like to select data in my queries only the list that is based on the user name currently logged in. I tried to use this query selection but it's still selecting all data that can be searched in the table. I would like the "u.name" is gonna be equal to the username in my other table.

```php
<?php
  $query = "SELECT m.*,u.name FROM mandates m, users u WHERE m.provider = u.name";
  $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
    foreach($query_run as $mandates)
      {
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a join

```
select u.name, m.* from users u
left join mandates m on (u.name = m.provider)
where u.name = (pass the username of whoever is logged in)
```

although i would suggest linking mandates to users by user ID instead of just the persons name in case of name changes etc.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your thoughts. I already got what I want to do. =)